# Время полуночи текущей даты в секундах UnixTimestamp

Tags: php

Необходимо на получить время полуночи текущей даты (например, 18.12.2019 0-00) в секундах unixtimestamp.
Как сделать это красивше на PHP?

Comment: Разве время по полуночи для разных дат не одно и то же? Я к тому, что и 18.12.2019, и 18.12.2099 время в полночь будет 00:00. Или вы думаете иначе? )

Comment: читаем внимательнее, время нужно получить в секундах unixtimestamp (количество секунд, прошедших с полуночи  1 января 1970 года).

Comment: `strtotime('18-12-2019 0:00:00')`

Comment: Guest, вы предлагаете сделать вот так strtotime(date('DD-MM-YYYY',time()).' 0:00:00') ? Может быть есть способ лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# получить ИМЕННО timestamp сегодняшней полуночи    
$time = (new DateTime('today midnight'))->getTimestamp();

# получить время полуночи 11 декабря
$test = new DateTime();
$test->setDate('2019',12,11);
$test->setTime(0,0,0);
$timeX = $test->getTimestamp();
```